# Adding the Spring Security taglib creates errors when tomcat is initiating beans

Tags: java, maven-2, spring-mvc, spring-security, taglib

I am working on a school project using Spring MVC (Spring 3.0.0).

Now everything works as it should, until I add the Spring Security taglib to pom.xml using

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.security.taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

(It may be worth noting that until I add the following maven repo, it can't even find the taglib).

```
<repository>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
        <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
</repository>
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
feb 08 2011 19:46:51 ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] while setting bean property 'securityMetadataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#11': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig] while setting constructor argument with key [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestKey]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#12': No matching factory method found: factory method 'createSingleAttributeList'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1305) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:557) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842) [org.springframework.context-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416) [org.springframework.context-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261) [org.springframework.web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192) [org.springframework.web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47) [org.springframework.web-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581) [catalina.jar:6.0.29]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [na:1.6.0_23]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [na:1.6.0_23]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [na:1.6.0_23]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [na:1.6.0_23]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) [bootstrap.jar:6.0.29]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) [bootstrap.jar:6.0.29]
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#11': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.access.SecurityConfig] while setting constructor argument with key [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.RequestKey]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#12': No matching factory method found: factory method 'createSingleAttributeList'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:383) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:161) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:586) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:886) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#12': No matching factory method found: factory method 'createSingleAttributeList'
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:502) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:964) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:868) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270) [org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
... 49 common frames omitted
```

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm tearing my hair out over this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your artifactId doesn't look right, try this:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

These are all the Spring Security related dependencies:-

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Just FYI, you don't need that repository configured because Spring Security exists in the default Maven repository.

Comment: I read that somewhere too, but when I add it maven says it can't find it, so I added the extra repo and then it could find it (I'm using IntelliJ 10 Ultimate with a seperate Maven 2).

Comment: It could be because you have the wrong `artifactId` in the first place. Are you able to find the taglibs based on the dependency I provide here?

Comment: This link shows you that Spring Security Taglibs exists in the default repo: http://www.mvnbrowser.com/artifact-details.html?groupId=org.springframework.security&artifactId=spring-security-taglibs&version=2.0.4&tab=REPOSITORIES#tabs

Comment: You sir, are my new hero, I removed the repo but added your dependencies and everything runs smooth as a baby's bottom :D